# What were the Rambam's sources?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, rambam

In the introduction to the Mishneh Torah, the Rambam indicates that his compilation of the entire Oral Torah is derived from a few key Jewish texts:

> ואין צריך לומר הגמרא עצמה הבבלית והירושלמית וספרא וספרי והתוספתא שהם צריכין דעת רחבה ונפש חכמה וזמן ארוך ואחר כך יודע מהם הדרך הנכוחה בדברים האסורים והמותרים ושאר דיני התורה היאך הוא. ומפני זה נערתי חצני אני משה בן מיימון הספרדי ונשענתי על הצור ברוך הוא ובינותי בכל אלו הספרים וראיתי לחבר דברים המתבררים מכל אלו החיבורים בענין האסור והמותר הטמא והטהור עם שאר דיני התורה
>
> Needless to say, [there is confusion] with the *Talmud* itself--both the Jerusalem and *Babylonian* *Talmuds*--the *Sifra*, the *Sifri*, and the *Tosefta*, for they require a breadth of knowledge, a spirit of wisdom, and much time, for appreciating the proper path regarding what is permitted and forbidden, and the other laws of the Torah. Therefore, I girded my loins-- I, Moses, the son of Maimon, of Spain. I relied on the Rock, blessed be He. I contemplated all these texts and sought to compose [a work which would include the conclusions] derived from all these texts regarding the forbidden and permitted, the impure and the pure, and the remainder of the Torah's laws.

My question is: Does the Rambam solely rely on the above sources (Talmuds, *Sifra*, *Sifri*, and *Tosefta*) when writing his Mishneh Torah?

I am not asking about how to find the sources for particular halakhot (cf. *Kesef Mishneh*). I'm more curious in seeing a list of all the sources that the Rambam used for the Mishneh Torah, which may or may not include Midrashic texts, Gaonic works, and [for *Yesodei HaTorah*] Greek sources.

Comment: The Rambam does write somewhere in Hilchos Kiddush HaChodesh that he took his knowledge of the astronomy necessary for these halachos from the Greeks. However I can't find where it is exactly. I think this question will be difficult to answer as perhaps he did take from many other sources when necessary to explain, etc.

Comment: @Yehoshua: (17:34): וטעם כל אלו החשבונות ומפני מה מוסיפים מנין זה ומפני מה גורעין, והיאך נודע כל דבר ודבר מאלו הדברים, והראיה על כל דבר ודבר, היא חכמת התקופות והגימטריות שחברו בה חכמי יון ספרים הרבה והם הנמצאים עכשיו ביד החכמים

Comment: So there you go!

Comment: @Yehoshua Interesting that you mentioned *Kiddush Hachodesh*. When I gave a lecture on this in my shul, a few months ago, I used Chabad's online translation of Ramba"m. In one of the footnotes, he emphasized the fact that Kiddush Hachodesh is the ONLY area where Ramba"m delves from his usual style and actually cites his sources PRIOR to delving into the particulars. IIRC, in Ramba"m's intro to *Yad Hachazaka* he himself says that he didn't want to include sources b/c the purpose of his work was to be concise and tell people what and how to do things, rather than get bogged down with sources.

Comment: @DanF:כולם בלשון ברורה ודרך קצרה עד שתהא תורה שבעל פה כולה סדורה בפי הכל בלא קושיא ולא פירוק. לא זה אומר בכה וזה בכה. אלא דברים ברורים קרובים נכונים על פי המשפט אשר יתבאר מכל אלו החיבורים והפירושים הנמצאים מימות רבינו הקדוש ועד עכשיו. עד שיהיו כל הדינין גלויין לקטן ולגדול בדין כל מצוה ומצוה ובדין כל הדברים שתיקנו חכמים ונביאים. כללו של דבר כדי שלא יהא אדם צריך לחיבור אחר בעולם בדין מדיני ישראל אלא יהא חיבור זה מקבץ לתורה שבעל פה כולה עם התקנות והמנהגות והגזירות שנעשו מימות משה רבינו ועד חבור הגמרא וכמו שפירשו לנו הגאונים בכל חיבוריהם שחיברו אחר הגמרא

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying what additional information you want.

Comment: On a related note, he does mention in his letter to R Pinchas Hadayan (Igros Rambam, ed Sheilat, p443) that anything in Mishna Torah where he does not state that he got it from somewhere ("ho'ru ha'geonim", "taka'nas acharonim hi") or thought up on his own (in his words, loosely translated, "it appears to me" or similar) is from a "clear" babvli, yerushalmi, tosefta, mishna, safara, or sifri.

Answer (score 4):

It is noteworthy that Rambam himself acknowledges Geonic works among his sources in the introduction to the Sefer Hamitzvot where he lists "Mishna, Talmud, Sifra, Sifre, and Tosefta, and more than that, all decrees and ordinances of the later Geonim, of blessed memory, as well all that they have explained and commented upon concerning the the prohibited and the permissible...” (quoted and translated in Introduction to the Code of Maimonides, p. 26).

He seems to acknowledge them in his introduction to the MT as well.

> וּמִפְּנֵי זֶה נִעַרְתִּי חָצְנִי אֲנִי מֹשֶׁה בֶּן מַיְימוֹן הַסְּפָרדִּי וְנִשְׁעַנְתִּי עַל הַצּוּר בָּרוּךְ הוּא וּבִינוֹתִי בְּכָל אֵלּוּ הַסְּפָרִים וְרָאִיתִי לְחַבֵּר דְּבָרִים הַמִּתְבָּרְרִים מִכָּל אֵלּוּ הַחִבּוּרִים בְּעִנְיַן הָאָסוּר וְהַמֻּתָּר הַטָּמֵא וְהַטָּהוֹר עִם שְׁאָר דִּינֵי הַתּוֹרָה. כֻּלָּם בְּלָשׁוֹן בְּרוּרָה וְדֶרֶךְ קְצָרָה עַד שֶׁתְּהֵא תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה כֻּלָּהּ סְדוּרָה בְּפִי הַכּל בְּלֹא קֻשְׁיָא וְלֹא פֵּרוּק. לֹא זֶה אוֹמֵר בְּכֹה וְזֶה בְּכֹה. אֶלָּא דְּבָרִים בְּרוּרִים קְרוֹבִים נְכוֹנִים עַל פִּי הַמִּשְׁפָּט אֲשֶׁר יִתְבָּאֵר מִכָּל אֵלּוּ הַחִבּוּרִים וְהַפֵּרוּשִׁים הַנִּמְצָאִים מִימוֹת רַבֵּנוּ הַקָּדוֹשׁ וְעַד עַכְשָׁו. עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כָּל הַדִּינִין גְּלוּיִין לַקָּטָן וְלַגָּדוֹל בְּדִין כָּל מִצְוָה וּמִצְוָה וּבְדִין כָּל הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁתִּקְּנוּ חֲכָמִים וּנְבִיאִים, כְּלָלוֹ שֶׁל דָּבָר כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא אָדָם צָרִיךְ לְחִבּוּר אַחֵר בָּעוֹלָם בְּדִין מִדִּינֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶלָּא יְהֵא חִבּוּר זֶה מְקַבֵּץ לַתּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה כֻּלָּה עִם הַתַּקָּנוֹת וְהַמִּנְהָגוֹת וְהַגְּזֵרוֹת שֶׁנַּעֲשׂוּ מִימוֹת משֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ וְעַד חִבּוּר הַגְּמָרָא **וּכְמוֹ שֶׁפֵּרְשׁוּ לָנוּ הַגְּאוֹנִים בְּכָל חִבּוּרֵיהֶם שֶׁחִבְּרוּ אַחַר הַגְּמָרָא**.

Although it could be understood that his intent is that his work is similar somehow to Geonic works, not that the Geonic works were his source.
R. Dr. Isadore Twersky writes in *Introduction to The Code of Maimonides* that it seems that Rambam's sources were pretty much every single Jewish text available to him. He suggests that his statements listing a small number of sources for his work were meant to downplay the significance of his work thus allaying some of the inevitable backlash against his monumental code.

He lists (p. 52)  Masechet Sofrim, Masechet derekh erets, Pirkei de-R. Eliezer, Avot de-R. Nattan, Pesikta, Mekchilta of R. Shimon, Sifre Zuta, and derekh Erets Zuta. Additionally (p. 53), works of R. Moses of Cordova, Shimmusha Rabba, Shmuel ben Chofni, R. Nissim Gaon, and R. Saadya Gaon. Lastly (p. 57) he utilizes Onkelos' translation of the Torah.

Comment: I'm sure he did use every text available, and I'd like to know what that library looks like. I realize it might be impossible to list every source, but I have yet to see such a list attempted and think it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

look at the introduction of the book "yam shel shlomo" on bava kama. there he says how one doesn't know where the rambam gets his information from, making it difficult to ask contradictions, for we don't know where he came from. part of it being the fact he never quotes.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, and it is untrue that we cannot make educated guesses about his sources, especially when he himself notes them sometimes; particularly in his responsa, and we can further find word for word quotes from earlier sources.

Comment: There are plenty of commentaries that cite the Rambam's sources. I agree with mevaqesh that this doesn't answer the question.