# Did Rambam have Rashi's works?

Tags: history, rambam, rashi, provenance, rishonim

While the [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) lived a century after [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi), I cannot recall ever seeing or hearing the Rambam cite or mention Rashi or any of his works.

Is there any evidence that Rambam had access to Rashi's works? Did Rashi's works even reach the lands in which the Rambam lived while the Rambam was still alive? Is there any comment of Rambam which, in all likelihood, came from a comment of Rashi?

Comment: rashshi's books came to yaman in around the 1500s with ashkanazim coming to yaman as a pit stop on their way to india. the teimonim would take books from them to copy and give back. it is said the rashshi of teimon is more authentic as their girso is older and didnt change with time as it did in europe. sometimes the ashkanazim would leave early and the teimonim would beg them to stay a little more so they can finish copying the books. sometimes they would finish after the 2nd batch of ashkanazim came.

Comment: i also have a hebrew piece which deals with your question. if anyone wants to read it and sum it up as an answer go ahead: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlY01rMVBjM09Qc0E/view?usp=sharing כלום לא נצנץ פירוש רש"י בבית מדרשו של הרמב"ם and the paper in the first paragraph that is being talked about is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlaWp5SDhuUWxkNW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also have this הרמב"ם במזרח הים התיכון "קוראיו המסתייגים" של רש"י https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqleEs0RGIxR2NWaFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqld05DLUJZZUJESmc/view?usp=sharing english version

Comment: Does the Rambam ever mention other post-Talmud commentators?  In particular, his great predecesssor in Egypt, Saadia Gaon?

Answer (score 16):

**Did Rashi's works even reach the lands in which the Rambam lived?**

To summarize [Prof. Shamma Friedman](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9F)'s [piece](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlY01rMVBjM09Qc0E/view?usp=sharing), scholars in the early 20th century assumed from Rambam's silence, that he did not have access to Rashi's works, and furthermore, that they were generally unavailable in Egypt at that time.

Additionally, we can infer from Rambam's early commentaries to parts of the Talmud, that he did not  have access to Rashi's works at the time.

However, Rambam's son [Rabbenu Avraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Moses_ben_Maimon) clearly had some familiarity with Rashi,[5]  as did his Egyptian brother in law, Rabbenu Perachya,[6] and even Rabbenu Chanael Bar Shemuel, Rabbenu Avraham's father in law, a member of Rambam's court in Egypt, had familiarity with Rashi.[7] Rav Yosef Rosh HaSeder, another Egyptian contemporary of Rambam, was also familiar with Rashi.[8]

**Was Rambam still alive when Rashi's works reached Egypt?**

Given that his younger contemporaries were familiar with Rashi, it is probable that Rambam was still alive when Rashi's works reached Egypt. (Because the only scenario in which he would have been dead at the time, has him dying just before their arrival, providing a very short span of possible time for their arrival, whereas if he were alive when they arrived, there is a much broader possible window for their arrival.)

However, given that Rambam never actually quotes Rashi by name, our only way of knowing whether he was still alive when Rashi's works reached Egypt is by looking for hints of Rashi in the writings of Rambam, which takes us to the last question:

**Is there any comment of Rambam which, in all likelihood, came from a comment of Rashi?**

If Rambam indeed gained access to Rashi's works later in his life, how could we detect the influence of Rashi? One indicator would be cases in which Rambam changed his view on something to accord with the view of Rashi.

One example of such a change this regards the Mishnah in Bava Metziah (7:2):

> ואלו אוכלין מן התורה העושה במחובר לקרקע בשעת גמר מלאכה ובתלוש מן הקרקע עד שלא נגמרה מלאכתו בדבר שגדולו מן הארץ ואלו שאין אוכלין העושה במחובר לקרקע בשעה שאין גמר מלאכה ובתלוש מן הקרקע מאחר שנגמרה מלאכתו ובדבר שאין גדולו מן הארץ
>
> Now, the following [laborers] may eat [of that upon which they are employed] according to scriptural law: he who is engaged upon that which is attached to the soil when its labor is finished, and upon that which is detached from the soil before its labor is completed, providing that it is something that grows from the earth. but the following may not eat: he who is engaged upon that which is attached to the soil. [(Trans. Soncino)](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Baba_Metzia.pdf)

This translation follows Rashi (bottom of Bava Metziah 87a) who interprets "עד שלא נגמרה מלאכתו" as meaning that the process of development of the plant is not complete.

However, in his commentary to the Mishnah, Rambam, interprets it as referring to stages of the labor of laborer; not stages of development of the plant. This interpretation is also evident in his Sefer Hamitzvot (267). Similarly, in the first edition of Hilchot Sechirut (12:2), he writes:

> והעושה במחובר אינו אוכל אלא כשיגמור מלאכתו אבל בשעת מלאכה הרי הוא בלא תעשה...אלא כל זמן שהוא עוסק בקצירה לא יניף

In these three works Rambam clearly disagrees with Rashi. However, in later editions of this halacha, we find Rambam switching to Rashi's understanding that גמר מלאכה refers to the plant; not the person. His later wording reads:

> הפועלין שהן עושין בדבר שגדוליו מן הארץ בין בתלוש בין במחובר, ועדיין לא נגמרה מלאכתו

This term מלאכה now refers to the process of the plant's growth.

In later manuscripts, Rambam completely removes the role of the laborer, fully accepting Rashi's explanation that the only distinction revolves around the plant. He writes:

> שהעושה בתלוש אוכל בדבר שלא לאכול נגמרה מלאכתו למעשר ולחלה

In conclusion, there is still no evidence that Rambam was exposed to Rashi's works. However, the degree to which his younger contemporaries were familiar with Rashi's works, is at least sufficient to question the formerly forgone conclusion that Rambam did not see Rashi. At least one interesting change of opinion by Rambam to Rashi's view is certainly suggestive.

---

[5] He writes in Shu"t Birkat Avraham (29): 
ושמעתי שהרב רבנו שלמה הצרפתי ז"ל כך פירש חבטן קצצן אבל לא ראיתי דבריו בזה הענין. Clearly he was familiar with some of his teachings. His comment that he has not seen the Rashi implies that it might have been assumed that he had seen Rashi. His clarification that he has not seen Rashi's words *regarding this matter* suggest that he has seen other works of Rashi. He also quotes Rashi's Torah commentary, and in *HaMaspik* (ed. Dana p. 137-8) he quotes the *Sefer HaPardes*.

[6] He quotes Rashi by name several times such as in his commentary to Shabbat.

[7] See for example his commentary to the Rif to Kiddushin, 2b where he quotes Rashi by name.

[8] He references Rashi's commentaries to Pesachim, Bava Kamm,Avodah Zara, and Chullin.

Comment: Very interesting. OAn other question very interesting for me is the absence of interaction Baal Hamaor Rambam.

Comment: @kouty I never heard of any interaction. Baal Hameor was in Provence, and IIRC died even before Raavad. It was the next generation of Provence that Rambam interacted with, such as Ri MiLunel; a student of Raavad. I dint remember any indication that works from Provence reached Rambam in Egypt. He does, however, mention Raavad, as the great rabbi of Posquerres.

Comment: +1 Ri Migash wrote perushim and do not mention Rashi. Rambam has few properly pilpulic works. He accorded a major importance to the massoret and for Rambam Rashi was no part of the massoret in halacha. I heard that the netsiv spoke about the massorot of Chachme sfarad in introduction to sheiltot

Comment: @kouty Ri Migash lived significantly earlier than Rambam. although he lived in spain, rather that egypt IIRC, Rashis works had not yet spread there; he was only a litle younger than Rashi. Even the Rokeach who died almost 100 tears after Ri Migash, and lived in Germany rather than Spain, still only had Rashi on parts of Shas.

Comment: During his later years in Egypt, he had no time, and learned some Torah "only on Shabbos". During the week he was occupied entirely with healing the Muslim aristocracy, studying medicine, and under great duress answering letters. See Igros Harambam, ed. Sheilas. It is therefore certainly possible that Rashi's writings reached Egypt then, but he had no time to study it.

Comment: It is also quite likely he did not view it as a practical use of his time, being obviously well versed in Talmud. He is quite vocal about what is a worthwhile use of time when studying Torah, once one has reached a certain level of proficiency, as expressed in several letters from him (again see ed. Sheilas).

Comment: @Jeff Yes I am aware of his letter regarding his lack of time, and am also aware of the varying importance of study after proficiency. E.g. P'er HaDor 10. And his encouragement that R. Yosef Ben Yehuda focus on studying the MT, and Rif and turn to the Talmud to resolve contradictions (found in R. Qafih's Igrot HaRambam: Iggeret L'talmido R. Yosef ben Yehuda). || Nevertheless, Rambam did master shocking amounts of Torah literature, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57434/8775). And [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83301/8775).

Comment: [cont.] nevertheless the fact that Rashi reached Egypt during his time at least allows for the possibility that he saw it, although you are right (and I am sure Dr. Friedman realises as well) that it by no means guarantees it. His later writings which are consistent with Rashi, noted by Dr. Friedman, are thus not conclusive, but certainly fascinating.

Comment: [Thought I'd note explicit source, since some may complain that claiming he learned Torah "only on Shabbos" is extreme without source; Sheilat P313, written ~1190, ~15 years before his passing; I believe same one @mevaqesh mentions to "R. Yosef Ben Yehuda focus on studying the MT...". Also p551 to R.S. Ibn Tibon implying that even on Shabbos was very constrained in what he could study, most of Shabbos involved with Torah/Halacha for local community members. For several of those years also very sick (see to Chachmei Luniel) So at least last ~15 years reasonable he couldn't learn Rashi.]

Comment: Your footnotes only start at 5?

Comment: @doniel I was getting thrown off with my footnotes interfering with links, so I used non overlapping numbers. A crude solution.

Answer (score 6):

The Mishnah in Pesachim 4:10 states that Hezekiah hid the Book of Remedies. Rambam in his commentary quotes an explanation of this.

> ששמעתי וגם פירשו לי ששלמה חבר ספר רפואות שאם חלה אדם באיזו מחלה שהיא
>   פנה אליו ועשה כמו שהוא אומר ומתרפא וראה חזקיה שלא היו בני אדם בוטחים
>   בה' במחלותיהם אלא על ספר הרפואות עמד וגנזו
>
> I heard, and they also explained to me, that Solomon wrote the Book of
>   Remedies so that if someone would take ill with whatever ailment, he
>   would turn to it and do as it says and be healed. And Hezekiah saw
>   that people were not trusting in Hashem with their ailments, but [were
>   trusting] the Book of Remedies [so] he got up and hid it.

This explanation is basically the explanation of Rashi ([Pesachim 56a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=56&format=pdf) and [Berachos 10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=10b&format=pdf)), perhaps indicating that Rambam was aware of at least one comment of Rashi.

Answer (score -2):

There are some who record that Rashi, in a self imposed exile, passed through Egypt and met the Rambam. 
The Rambam hosted him and gave him huge honour upon discovering Rashi's wisdom etc.

Seder Hadoros: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=221&hilite=

Also:
https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_6618_120.pdf

Comment: Rashi: 1040-1105. Rambam: 1138-1204. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: I agree. And theres plenty who disagree with the above sources. I just thought I'd share what "some record"