# Was the Rambam familiar with 'Tosfos'?

Tags: rambam, tosfot

Is there any evidence attesting to the fact that Rambam was even remotely familiar with the writings of any of the Ba'ale Tosafot?

The reason I ask is because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elhanan_ben_Isaac_of_Dampierre) makes the claim that the tosafist 'ELHANAN BEN ISAAC OF DAMPIERRE' was "often quoted by contemporary scholars, and is mentioned in 'Minḥat Yehudah', 'Shibbole ha-Leḳeṭ' and **Rambam's 'Sefer Hafla'ah'**." This suggests Rambam knew about some of the Tosafot. The footnote is a link to the [JewishEncyclopedia entry](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5567-elhanan-ben-isaac-of-dampierre) but it doesn't direct you to any specific source in Sefer Hafla'ah and it all sounds suspect.

Comment: As far as I know, the Rambam never mentions an individual scholar in Mishneh Torah at all

Comment: Related through ק"ו https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66565/15256

Comment: There's a language of the Rambam in one of his correspondence where he refers critically to the baalei tosfos as something like "those cold sages from the north." I don't remember off-hand where I saw it, but I definitely saw it inside. When I first saw it, it was in the context of "the only place where the Rambam directly relates to the baalei tosfos." Try looking around in his teshuvos and igros.

Comment: I believe seeing that he corresponded with some during the controversy over his writings, but I doubt any would be referenced in his published works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference is supposed to be not to the Rambam's Hafla'ah, but to the Teshuvot Maimoniyot on his Sefer Hafla'ah [4](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14275&st=&pgnum=210), which is in fact signed אלחנן ב"ר יצחק (with help from Gross' [*Gallia Judaica*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k14109950/f189.item) cited in the Jewish Encyclopedia's bibliography).